# How to activate this datepicker on `onLoad` event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use this datepicker for my project. I know how to use script when I change the date value. However I do no know how to use it on page load.

```
$('.date_set .date').datepicker({
    startView           : 0,        
    forceParse          : false,
    autoclose           : true,
    startDate           : besok,
    format              : "dd/mm/yyyy",
    daysOfWeekDisabled  : [0,6]
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I tried to use `'changeDate,load'` but it still not launch the `alert`.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin you are using?

Comment: paste you full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('.date_set .date').datepicker({
    startView           : 0,        
    forceParse          : false,
    autoclose           : true,
    startDate           : besok,
    format              : "dd/mm/yyyy",
    daysOfWeekDisabled  : [0,6]
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    alert($(this).val());
}).trigger('changeDate');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll approve this answer when the site allow me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.show` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show), as in `$('.date').datepicker("show")`, to open the datepicker at any time. ;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.date').datepicker({
    startView: 0,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: null,
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
  });


  // Show the datepicker
  $('.date').datepicker("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="date"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option is : `$("#datepicker").focus();` and place it before your script (if it's synchronously loads)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`startDate           : besok,` seems this is the issue.
Remove this line or change it to a string that matches `format`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muttalebm/LgworLq4/)

Comment: The ajax run well. I only do not know how to  run it  `onload`